# pyspark - convert collected list to tuple

Tags: python, pyspark

My dataframe is given below:

```
+----------------------------------+
| invoice_id | newcolor            |
+------------+---------------------+
|         1  | [red, white, green] | 
+------------+---------------------+
|         2  | [red, green]        |       
+------------+---------------------+
```

I need a new column with following:

```
[('red', 'color'), ('white', 'color), ('green','color)]
[('red', 'color'), ('green','color)]
```

Comment: Your expected output isn't a valid python data structure and you've not shown anything you've tried to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: you can create similar output dataframe like this: df = spark.createDataFrame([
        (0, [('red', 'tshirt'), ('red', 'wallet'), ('black','jeans')]),
            (1, [('red','wallet'), ('red','tshirt'), ('blue','shirt'), ('black','wallet'), ('black', 'jeans')]),
                (2, [('black','wallet'), ('black','jeans')])
                ], ["id", "items"])

Comment: That wasn't what I said in my comment at all.

Comment: so my expected output is a valid dataframe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `udf` function as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
def addColor(x):
    return [[color, 'color'] for color in x]

udfAddColor = F.udf(addColor, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
```

and then use it with `.withColumn` as

```
df.withColumn('newcolor', udfAddColor(df.newcolor)).show(truncate=False)
```

You should have your desired output as

```
+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|invoice_id|newcolor                                      |
+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|1         |[[red, color], [white, color], [green, color]]|
|2         |[[red, color], [green, color]]                |
+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```